# Solving a second order ODE that has a summation term

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I have this differential equation that I'm trying to solve numerically.

[image]

I am trying to look for way of solving this problem in python using loop in scipy or other method when n is large, say, 50.

I am able to solve it when n=1.

[image]

Here is the code I used to do that.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy as sp 
from scipy.integrate import odeint 
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp 
#SOLVING THE GOVERNING DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION 
t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000) 
A = 2 
B = 3 
a = 2 
b = -3 
c = 2 
omega = 20 
def dSdt(t, S): 
    y, P = S 
    dSdt = [P, (A/a)*np.cos(omega*t) + (B/a)*np.sin(omega*t) - (b/a)*P - (c/a)*y] 
    return dSdt 
y_0 = 0 
P_0 = 0 
sol = solve_ivp(dSdt, t_span = (0, max(t)), y0 = [y_0, P_0], t_eval=t) 
time = sol.t 
disp_value = sol.y[0]  
plt.plot(time, disp_value)
```

But how do I extend this to the more general case?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You just need to add a `for` loop into your function. Or, even better, a vectorized sum using numpy.

Answer (score 2):

You can update your model to include the whole sum directly and why not parametrize it:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy import integrate

def model(t, x, a, b, c, As, Bs, omegas):
    rhs = np.sum([
        A * np.cos(omega * t) + B * np.sin(omega * t)
        for A, B, omega in zip(As, Bs, omegas)
    ])
    return np.array([
        x[1],
        (rhs - b * x[1] - c * x[0]) / a 
    ])
```

Then the following call, solve the IVP:

```
a = 2
b = -3
c = 2
As = [2, 8, 14] 
Bs = [3, 11, -2]
omegas = [20, 40, 60]
t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000) 

solution = integrate.solve_ivp(
    model, [t.min(), t.max()], [0, 0],
    t_eval=t, args=(a, b, c, As, Bs, omegas)
)
```

Which returns the same solution than @YakovDan because of linearity but with a single call to `solve_ivp`.

Comment: This is what I was suggesting in the comments.

Comment: Why not just `sum(As*np.sin(omegas*t)+Bs*np.sin(omegas*t))`. I'm not sure if at this point using `np.sum` leads to the same operations, or if it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your ODE is linear, so you can just iterate over the parameters, then sum:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy as sp 
from scipy.integrate import odeint 
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp 
#SOLVING THE GOVERNING DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION 


def get_dSdt(i):
    def dSdt(t, S): 
        y, P = S 
        dSdt = [P, (A[i]/a)*np.cos(omega[i]*t) + (B[i]/a)*np.sin(omega[i]*t) - (b/a)*P - (c/a)*y]
        return dSdt 
    return dSdt     

n = 3 # for example

t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000) 
A = [2, 8, 14] 
B = [3, 11, -2] 
a = 2 
b = -3 
c = 2 
omega = [20, 40, 60]
y_0 = 0 
P_0 = 0 
disp_value = 0
for i in range(n):
    sol = solve_ivp(get_dSdt(i), t_span = (0, max(t)), y0 = [y_0, P_0], t_eval=t) 
    time = sol.t 
    disp_value += sol.y[0]  
plt.plot(time, disp_value)
```

Note that the function `get_dSdt` takes an integer `i` and returns your `dSdt` function, except with parameter values defined for the index `i`